# Parsing a simple Json string

Tags: c#, android, json, string, mobile

I have gotten a Json string to parse before that was an array of objects much longer than just a simple string, which makes me think that I'm doing something wrong with the formatting.

Here is word for word what our webservice is outputting as the json string:

```
{"news":"What is Legal/Awesome Dre"}
```

the first part is simply what I named the string in the application (news) and the second part is the string that will be changing as the song does which is why I would like to pull in a simple string of it.

When I run the app I'm getting a parse error at these lines:

```
Console.Out.Writeline (content);

news = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
```

The application output will show the Json string as it is on the website, but I get an error right after that's telling me Invalid Token: startPath... which last time meant that my Json string was formatted wrong for how I need to grab the data.
Anyone can help me with this?

(P.S. I am working in Xamarin Studio (mono for android) using C#, if that makes any difference)

Comment: what is the type of news, you want to assign the de-serialized value to? Is it dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your serialized JSON object isn't a string, it's an object with the string value you want at the `"news"` property/key/name. This is a simple way to get the string:

```
dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);
string news = jsonObj.news;
```

Or you can use an anonymous type:

```
var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(content, new { news = "" });
string news = jsonObj.news;
```

Or create a type with a `string News` property:

```
MyNewsType jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyNewsType>(content);
string news = jsonObj.News;
```

These all work in the following way:

```
var content = @"{""news"":""What is Legal/Awesome Dre""}";
// above code
Console.WriteLine(news); // prints "What is Legal/Awesome Dre"
```

Comment: thank you, the options above worked like a charm, specifically:
var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(content, new { news = "" });
string news = jsonObj.news;

Just a follow up question, but this is essentially just creating a Json object that is storing my string in the objects ".news" property and then setting my created string equal to the contents of the ".news" property?

Comment: It's more accurate to say that it's creating an object of an anonymous type, not a Json object. I just called it `jsonObj` because I couldn't think of a better name. The rest of what you said is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put square bracket in your JSON:

```
[{"news":"What is Legal/Awesome Dre"}]
```